# Flex tab navigator truncates the labels

Tags: apache-flex, tabs, truncated, tabnavigator

I have a flex application which has 5 tabs from our application and 2 other tabs will be rendered from the other application at run time . We maintain a permissions database to render the tabs to a particular user. For eg: a user **User1** logged in has the permissions only to view first 4 tabs then the other 3 tabs would be removed from the tab navigator by checking the permissions. The problem is when the first 2 tabs are removed from the permissions the remaining tabs displayed are shown with the labels truncated. I tried searching the Google but they have answered is  only for the static tabs. Here tabs are rendered dynamically based on the permissions provided to the user. I cannot use the **creationComplete** method on tab navigator because  I'm adding the other application's 2  tabs after creating it and these two tabs were unknown to that method of tab navigator. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include your code in the post - along with any screen-shots, error messages, etc which are relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I was using **fl:SuperTabNavigator** now moved to **mx:TabNavigator.**

this solved the problem